# check by group if they meet a list and if not, create new rows with missing values

Tags: sql, sas

I want to check by group if they meet a list and if not, create a new row with all the missing values. If you don't know in SAS but know in SQL Python or R please let me know. It could give me an idea.

eg.

```
COUNTRY  OBJECT
U.S       table
U.S.      chair
France    chair
```

if country not in all ('table','chair') then create new row with missing value.

```
COUNTRY  OBJECT
U.S       table
U.S.      chair
France    chair
France    table
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select c.country, o.object
from (select distinct country from t) c cross join
     (select distinct object from t) o;
```

Answer (score 2):

If all values are in the table, SPARSE in PROC FREQ is a nice little trick. It essentially forces a cross join between all possible values. If you do not have all the values in the table somewhere then you need a different approach, typically the PRELOADFMT option.

```
proc freq data=have;
table country*object / sparse list out=want;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

One idiotmatic SAS option is to use `PROC FREQ` with `SPARSE`.  The below does what you ask:

```
data have;
input COUNTRY  $ OBJECT $;
datalines;
U.S.      table
U.S.      chair
France    chair
;;;;
run;

proc freq data=have;
  tables country*object/sparse out=want(keep=country object);
run;
```

It wouldn't necessarily work with other variables, however; you'd have to merge that on to the main dataset (or left join or whatever) to get other variables' data.